# selenium : can not automate youTube 's play-pause and zoom in-out

Tags: selenium, xpath, youtube, css-selectors, classname

need to automate this link:-

---

### button class="ytp-large-play-button ytp-button" aria-label="Play"

I have tried with  css selector , class name , xpath ; but it won't work with selenium

```
xpath ->  //*[@id="player_uid_334744221_1"]/div[18]/div[1]/div[2]/button 

xpath ->  (//button[@aria-label='Play'])

classname -> ytp-large-play-button

css selec -> .ytp-large-play-button.ytp-button
```

image:-
[image]

PS:- for reference you can pick any youtube URL.

check out my screen:-
difference between youtube link and my site's youtube refrence URL link is.
user need to click on a play button first to play video, where in youtube , it automatically play when user click on a video.
[image]

i think that we need to write a code , where first of all need a focus on a play button and click on it. after that play-pause , volume , zoom in out button will be shown in panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To identify the **`Play`** / **`Pause`** button you can use the following line of code :

> **Noe** : Ensure that you are using the latest build of **`Selenium v3.8.1`**, **`GeckoDriver v0.19.1`** and **`Firefox Quantum`** Browser.

- **`Java`**

  ```
  package demo;

  import org.openqa.selenium.By;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class YouTube_Play_Pause_Button 
  {
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
          WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPS89xCgNhk&t=528s");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='ytp-play-button ytp-button']"))).click();
          System.out.println("Play/Pause Button Pressed");
      }

  }
  ```

Console Output :

```
Play/Pause Button Pressed
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //button[@class='ytp-play-button ytp-button'] (tried for 50 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Comment: i have updated the time , even though display error.

Comment: difference between youtube link and my site's youtube refrence URL link is.
user need to click on a play button first to play video, where in youtube , it automatically play when user click on a video. please check the image that i have uploaded, you get some idea from it.

Comment: i think that we need to write a code , where first of all need a focus on a play button and click on it. after that play-pause , volume , zoom in out button will be shown in panel.